# Warning: File_Get_Contents in php 8.1 wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I recently changed the php version from 7.4 to 8.1
But after the change, I get an error when posting content in WordPress

You need to know that despite this error, the article will be sent, but this error has bothered me
I activated the WordPress debugger, the error was referring to the active plugin in WordPress

This line:

```
$pictureFile = file_get_contents($imageFilePath);
```

WP_DEBUG :

> Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/mp3publisher7/mp3-post-publisher.php:113
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/mp3publisher7/mp3-post-publisher.php(113): file_get_contents()
>
> #1 /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): save_mp3_post_publisher()
>
> #2 /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
>
> #3 /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
>
> #4 /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(4717): do_action()
>
> #5 /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_html/wp-includes/revision.php(337): wp_insert_post()
>
> #6 /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_html/wp-includes/revision.php(191): _wp_put_post_revision()
>
> #7 /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): wp_save_post_revision()
>
> #8 /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
>
> #9 /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
>
> #10 /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(4686): do_action()
>
> #11 /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(4819): wp_insert_post()
>
> #12 /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_html/wp-admin/includes/post.php(426): wp_update_post()
>
> #13 /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_htm/wp-admin/post.php(227): edit_post()
>
> #14 {main} thrown in /home/admin/domains/xxx.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/mp3publisher7/mp3-post-publisher.php on line 113

More complete code of this plugin :

```
$mp3FilePath = get_attached_file($_POST["mp3_file_id"]);
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($postId);
$imageFilePath = get_attached_file($thumb_id);

$pictureFile = file_get_contents($imageFilePath);

$info = array(
        "artist"=>$_POST["mp3_artist"],
        "album"=>$_POST["mp3_album"],
        "comment"=>$_POST["mp3_comment"],
        "title"=>$_POST["mp3_caption"],
        "cover_data" => array(
            array (
                'data'=> $pictureFile,
                'picturetypeid'=> 3,
                'mime'=> 'image/jpeg',
                'description' => 'My Picture'
            )
    )
```

When I disable this plugin, there is no problem in posting

After deleting the following line, the problem will be solved, but some parts of the plugin will not work anymore:

> // $pictureFile = file_get_contents($imageFilePath);

If anyone can please help. I can't think of anything anymore
tnx..........................

Comment: `$imageFilePath = get_attached_file($thumb_id);` is probably returning false. You'll need to figure out why.

Comment: The error is from plugin in the folder name **mp3publisher7**. I don't see this plugin on wordpress.org so I think you may have to contact plugin author and wait for them to update for PHP 8.1.

Comment: If I try to run `file_get_contents('');` since PHP 7.0+, the warning will be occur (if you don't see this it means you turned off error message). This means the plugin author did not write the code very well to prevent this. If you look where `$imageFilePath` come from, it come from [`get_attached_file()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_file/) which returns string or `false`. So, plugin author should not use it without value checked.

Comment: The author of this plugin is not available now. Please help

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs with the variable `$imageFilePath`. It's returning an error or a null value.

Try console log `echo("<script>console.log('The value of imageFilePath is : " . $imageFilePath . "');</script>");`